# Storing info locally without using NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I was wondering whether there are any other ways in swift to save data locally on device, which will be available also after app close without using `NSUserDefaults`.

If there are, in which cases is that specific solution preferable?

I know this is kind of general, but I know just this one way to do saving locally and from my experience, there is always more than one way to do something(unless there isn't).
Any answers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Search for "NSCoding" and "NSKeyedArchiver".

Comment: Search for "Core Data"

Comment: Thanks...having a good read right here!

Comment: Have you heard about file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are different ways to store data locally.

As you have mentioned one of them is
[NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

In addition to that you can also:

1. Use files such as [plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html), [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or your own custom format.
2. Use [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)
3. Use [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html)

   And also you can combine between those.

Here some nice post [Core Data VS SQLite](http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/ios-data-storage-core-data-vs-sqlite/240168843?pgno=2)

Now for:

> in which cases is that speciffic solution preferable

I would say that `NSUserDefaults` is good when you need to store some small pieces of data, for example: Numbers, Booleans, Strings.

Comment: So I'm guessing that Core Data is for storing more complex objects. Am I right?

Comment: There are also other options, namely iCloud and keychain.

Comment: iCloud for that purpose is a remote, not local service, I could just as easily used any other remote storage service.
Keychain is very problematic for the fact that buckup/restore won't pick it up and it's only accessible through the app you set it for...and sharing that info with other apps would require setting up Keychain group. I don't think I'll have any use for it. I rather simply encrypt the stored data if I want it secure.